# The error I am getting : TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list

Tags: python, list

I am getting this error when I am trying to iterate through a list that was generated from a csv and trying to find the list elements in a sentence.

```
df = pd.read_csv("List_keywords.csv")
search_keywords = df.values.tolist()
if (any(map(lambda word: word in utext, search_keywords))):
   print(utext)
```

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spcy.py", line 60, in <module>
    spacy_test(in_file)
  File "spcy.py", line 36, in spacy_test
    if (any(map(lambda word: word in utext, search_keywords))):
  File "spcy.py", line 36, in <lambda>
    if (any(map(lambda word: word in utext, search_keywords))):
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

The column which I am reading as the text has mixed content with integers, strings, words, and phrases while 'utext' is the input sentence

Thanks

Comment: The "left operand" in the error message is "word" (`word in utext`), which apparently is a list, not a (single) string.

Comment: Which suggests `search_keywords` is a list of lists. Have you tried printing `search_keywords` and check its type?

Comment: Note that a Pandas DataFrame will be (generally) two-dimensional. Getting its values, and converting them to a list, will keep that structure, effectively turning it into a list of lists.

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense. The issue was with the 'list'. So I used the column header to basically create the list and it works now.

Comment: @ary If your problem is solved you may close your question or answer your question and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was creating a list and not a list of lists as pointed out by 0 0

```
search_keywords = list(df["column_name "])
```